# Identify the value of the plaintext from a noised expression

Tags: paillier, decryption, proof-of-work

Having the following instructions:

1. Using Paillier encryption to encrypt $m$. So, we get $Enc(m)$
2. Multiply $Enc(m)$ and $A$ to Get $C$. So, $C = Enc(m).A $
3. Decrypt $C$ using Paillier Decryption algorithm ($Dec(Enc(m).A)$

Knowing the value of $A$, is there a possibility to have $Dec(C) = A.Dec(m)$ ?

How can we get the value of $Dec(m)$ in this case.

Comment: hint: See Wikipedia [Paillier cryptosystem#Homomorphic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem#Homomorphic_properties)

Comment: But in my case, I do not have a multiplication of two ciphertext or addition of two ciphertext. I have a multpilication of a ciphertext with a plaintext as C

Comment: Now, can you assume that $A=g^x$ for some $x$?